# CSS Media Query Not Working on Android 4.1.2 Jellybean

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following media query in my stylesheet which contains mobile styles. It works on devices running Android 5.0 Lollipop but the styles are not displayed on Android running 4.1.2 Jellybean. Is there different media query support for the different versions of Android?

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing end tag to first media query was causing problems in 4.1.2